# GCC differently treats an object and a static library regarding undefined symbols

Tags: gcc, linker, static-libraries, undefined-symbol

Recently I discoved that Linux linker does not fail due to undefined symbols from static libraries, however does fail due to the same undefined symbols if I link directly with te object files. Here is a simple example:

Source code:

```
$ cat main.c
int main() { return 0; } 
$ cat src.c
int outerUnusedFunc() {
    return innerUndefinedFunc();
}
int innerUndefinedFunc();
```

Creating *.o and *.a from it, comparing using "nm":

```
$ gcc -c -o main.o main.c
$ gcc -c -o src.o src.c
$ ar r src.a src.o
ar: creating src.a
$ nm src.o
                 U innerUndefinedFunc
0000000000000000 T outerUnusedFunc
$ nm src.a

src.o:
                 U innerUndefinedFunc
0000000000000000 T outerUnusedFunc
```

(Here we clearly see that both *.o and *.a contain the equal symbols list)

And now...

```
$ ld -o exe main.o src.o
src.o: In function `outerUnusedFunc':
src.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `innerUndefinedFunc'
$ echo $?
1
$ ld -o exe main.o src.a
$ echo $?
0
```

What is the reason for GCC to treat it differenty?

Answer (score 3):

If you read the [`static-libraries` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info)
it will explain why no object files from `src.a` are linked into your program, and therefore
why it doesn't matter what undefined symbols are referenced in them.

The difference between an object file `foo.o` and a static library `libfoo.a`, as linker inputs, is
that an object file is *always* linked into your program, unconditionally, whereas the same object file
in a static library library, `libfoo.a(foo.o)`, is extracted from `libfoo.a` and linked into
the program only if the linker *needs* it to carry on the linkage, as explained by the tag wiki.

Naturally, the linker will give errors only for undefined references in object files *that are linked into the program*.

The behaviour you are observing is behaviour of the *linker*, whether or not you invoke it via a GCC
front-end.

Giving the linker `foo.o` tells it: *I want this in the program*. Giving the linker
`libfoo.a` tells it: *Here are some object files that you might or might not need*.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It explained me what I didn't understand. I tried to create an atomic *.o from many *.o using "ld -r" and use this atomic *.o instead of the *.a.
I couldn't understand why linking of an exe fails with the atomic *.o (due to unused symbols, but reported as "undefined") and passes with *.a. According to that article linker doesn't analyse *.o and takes all symbols from it, no matter if they called or not, while *.a it treats differently, that is extracts, checks each *.o inside *.a and includes all symbols from *.o to the exe if at least one symbol of that *.o is called.

Answer (score 2):

In the second case — with static library — command line with  says "build exe from main.o and add all *required* things from src.a".
`ld` just ignores the library because no external symbols required for `main.o` (`outerUnusedFunc` is not referenced from `main.o`).

But in the first case command line says "build exe from main.o and src.o".
`ld` should place `src.o` content into output file.
Hence, it obligate to analyze `src.o` module, add `outerUnusedFunc` into output file and resolve all symbols for `outerUnusedFunc` despite it is unused.

You can enable garbage collection for code sections

```
gcc --function-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -o exe main.c src.c
```

In this case `outerUnusedFunc` (as well as all other functions) will be placed 
in separate section. `ld` will see that this section unused (no symbols referenced). It will remove all the section from output file so that `innerUndefinedFunc` would not be referenced and the symbol should not be resolved — the same result as for library case.

On the other hand, you can manually reference `outerUnusedFunc` as "undefined" so that `ld` should find it in library and add to output file.

```
ld -o exe main.o -u outerUnusedFunc src.a
```

in this case the same error (undefined reference to innerUndefinedFunc) will be produced.

Comment: That was exactly my question why GCC has more strict treatment about *.o.  Do you know what is the logic behind such a behaviour?